# SpringBoot embedded mongo test case exception

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

SpringBoot embedded mongo test case is throwing below exception with a @SpringBootTest configuration in test class.

TestMongo.java

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = AppConfig.class)
public class TestMongo {
  @Test
  public void testMongoTemplate(){
     // mongoTemplate code
  }

}
```

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/flapdoodle/embed/process/store/ExtractedArtifactStoreBuilder

Pom xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>cz.jirutka.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>embedmongo-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
            <version>1.46.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>cz.jirutka.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>embedmongo-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
        <version>1.46.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

should be changed to

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>cz.jirutka.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>embedmongo-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
        <version>1.46.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The compile scope can be omitted.